# Package Manager Console

Tags: .net

In Package  Manager Console there is an error like this.That time I want to Add Migrations.

```
Error Message: 
   "The process cannot access the file
   'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\__PSScriptPolicyTest_vhkzjull.ckn.ps1'
   because it is being used by another process. "
```

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: @Thalisha Can you provide more details about the problem you are facing
Like what did you do to get the error message,
And are you speaking about the VS Package manager console? If so can you add it to the question

Providing enough details in your question will help you get the question answered quickly

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS and/or Windows?